# Array merging in PHP

Tags: php

I have two arrays(cad_cons,man_cons) like

```
 cad_cons => 
array
  0 => string '' 
  1 => string '200' 
  2 => string '500' 
  3 => string '' 

man_cons => 
array
  0 => string '228.44' 
  1 => string '' 
  2 => string '' 
  3 => string '320.04'
```

But i need to merge like this

```
 cons=>
array
  0 => string '228.44' 
  1 => string '200' 
  2 => string '500' 
  3 => string '320.04'
```

Any Build in function available in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a combination of [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$a = ['', '200', '500', ''];
$b = ['228.44', '', '', '320.04'];

$a = array_filter($a); 
$b = array_filter($b);

print_r(array_merge($a, $b));
```

The above will give you.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 200
    [1] => 500
    [2] => 228.44
    [3] => 320.04
)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you want.

```
cons = array_merge(cad_cons,man_cons);
```

Official context

```
array array_merge ( array $array1 [, array $... ] )
```

source
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: No, this won't return the array OP wants, but `array:8 [
  0 => ""
  1 => "200"
  2 => "500"
  3 => ""
  4 => "228.44"
  5 => ""
  6 => ""
  7 => "320.04"
]
`

Comment: you might have to write a function.